# Passing URL parameters to Apache Zeppelin paragraph

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I need to pass request parameters to a specified zeppelin paragraph  have them available to the spark context. tbh this is proving a real nightmare. I can write some js in the %angular interpreter to retrieve the query parameters but as z.angularBind("myparam", "value") *currently only works in Spark Interpreter(scala)* I can't use this.

My next thought was to retrieve the Paragraph and/or Notebook object - I'm thinking it *must* have a reference somewhere to the url that invoked it. However all you can easily get is the paragraphId/noteId from the InterpreterContext.

Anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you find out ?

Comment: Not sure it's possible - best alternative was to create a new notebook using the rest api [link] http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0-SNAPSHOT/rest-api/rest-notebook.html#create-a-new-note and passing in the json string in the body

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters through [dynamic form](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/manual/dynamicform.html). Create the parameters through dynamic form for your notebook. To pass a value for the dynamic form, use the following

```
{
  "params": {
  "formLabel1": "value1",
  "formLabel2": "value2"
  }
}
```

Doc: https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.2/rest-api/rest-notebook.html#run-a-paragraph-synchronously

Note that you can pass params only when you want to run a single paragraph.